# Error in footnote inside figure caption

Tags: captions, footnotes

I am trying to insert a footnote inside a figure caption, but I am getting the following errors:

```
*Argument of \@caption has an extra }.*

*Paragraph ended before \@caption was complete.*
```

There aren't any visible mistakes in the compiled document, but I'm curious why this error keeps appearing.

A more complet code follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\renewcommand\contentsname{Sumário}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{centering}
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{FOTO_FRENTE_SIMAO.JPG}
\caption{E.E.B Simão José Hess. Fonte: \footnote{http://escolasimaohess.blogspot.com.br/}}
\end{centering}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it makes no sense to have a footnote in the caption. It will not be printed. You have to use `\footrnotemark` and `\footnotetext` or a `minipage` or ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command `\footnotetext` must be on the same page where the float appears!
By the way: `\centering` is a command and not an environment. And use the optional argument of `\caption` without the footnote mark. It makes no sense to have it
in the list of figures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\renewcommand\contentsname{Sumário}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \centering
            %\includegraphics[width=10cm]{FOTO_FRENTE_SIMAO.JPG}
            \caption[E.E.B Simão José Hess.]{E.E.B Simão José 
            Hess.Fonte:\footnotemark}
    \end{figure}

\footnotetext{\url{http://escolasimaohess.blogspot.com.br/}}

\end{document}
```